# Are dramas which are audible but have no videos off topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

[The Importance of Being Earnest - Where do the cucumber sandwiches go in the second episode?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37210/the-importance-of-being-earnest-where-do-the-cucumber-sandwiches-go-in-the-sec?noredirect=1#comment57546_37210)

Argument for off topic vote there was that it is only audible, cannot be seen.

Is there a rule here which says the the dramas which have only audios and not videos are offtopic here?

Comment: You mean a rule other than being a site about movies and TV? ;-)

Answer (score 6):

According to your question this play is from BBC. Since it's only audio I understand it's from BBC radio or is produced by BBC for some kind of sound-only media. This means that it's not related to movies or TV and is off-topic.

From [Help](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Movies & TV Stack Exchange is for Movie & TV enthusiasts and experts
>   alike!
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> Analysis of content or theme of all forms of Movies and TV series
>   Identifying a Movie or TV series (see below for details) Questions
>   about a Movie or TV show's production. The works of a director / an
>   actor / a writer related to Movies & TV
>
> Our on topic content also includes Made-For-TV movies, Web-series,
>   Direct-to-DVD, and Mini-Series.

Comment: "some kind of sound-only media" - this is also known as "radio" :)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I didn't mean 'mass  media', but 'media' in its general meaning. For sound-only it's not  only  radio, but also  CD-AUDIO,  vinyl record, MP3, etc.

Comment: Not to mention podcasts...